Supabase JS Client query returning null for Joined Data when using "or" filter
I am using the Supabase JS Client to fetch data from my work_orders table and join it with the customers and synced_users tables. The query works perfectly without any filters, but when I add an or() filter to search within the customers table, the customer data returns as null if there is no match. Instead, I would expect the entire work order to be excluded from the results if the filter doesn’t match any customer data.
Here is my code :
async getworkordersWithCustomerAndEmployees(segment: Database['public']['Enums']['workorder_status'], search?: string) {
    const query = supabase
        .from('work_orders')
        .select('*, customer:customers(customer_nr, first_name, last_name, adress), employees:synced_users_work_orders(...synced_users(id, first_name, last_name, avatar_url))')
        .is('deleted_at', null)
        .eq('status', segment);

    if (search) {
        // search by customer_nr, first_name, last_name (only returns null for customer if no customer is found, not the work order itself)
        query = query.or(`customer_nr.ilike.%${search}%,first_name.ilike.%${search}%,last_name.ilike.%${search}%`, { referencedTable: 'customers' });
    }
    
    const { data, error } = await query.returns<(Tables<'work_orders'> & { customer: Pick<Tables<'customers'>, 'customer_nr' | 'first_name' | 'last_name' | 'adress'> } & { employees: Pick<Tables<'synced_users'>, 'id' | 'first_name' | 'last_name' | 'avatar_url'>[] })[]>();

    if (error) { useGlobalStore().handleError('getworkordersWithCustomerAndEmployees error', error); return; }
    
    if (data) {
        console.log('getworkordersWithCustomerAndEmployees data', data);
        this.workordersWithCustomerAndEmployees = data;
    }
},

I have tried using { foreignTable: 'customers' } but this did not help.
And I have tried using different methods like filter:
if (search) {
    // Using the filter method to apply the search conditions to the customer table
    query = query.filter('customer.customer_nr', 'ilike', `%${search}%`)
                     .or(`customer.first_name.ilike.%${search}%,customer.last_name.ilike.%${search}%`);
}

Maybe im structuring my query all wrong, I feel like i'm close.
Does anyone have an idea?
